# How to copy textbox value in a word document into a textbox in a different word document with VBA (MS Word 2003)

Tags: vba, ms-word

Hopefully an easy question.

I have two word documents (MS Word 2003), each document has a text box object.  Upon pressing a command button, I want the text that is in the text box in one document ("Reference_Text.docx") to go into the text box of another document.

Below shows the code I am trying to use in an event when the command button is pushed.  I am trying to have the text box (txtLocation_Analysis) populated with the text that is in "txtLocation_Analysis_1", which is in the Reference_Text.docx file.

```
Dim objWord As Word.Application 
Dim wd As Word.Document
Set wd = objWord.Documents.Open("C:\Users\Tim\Desktop\Reference_Text.docx")

ThisDocument.txtLocation_Analysis.Text = '(Want to call a "txtLocation_Analysis_1.text" from wd document)
```

Let me know if this makes sense - and if any help can be provided please :)

Hugh

Comment: The wording of the third paragraph is not really clear. What exactly do you want?

Comment: I've redone the description, let me know if this helps?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
ThisDocument.txtLocation_Analysis.Text = "txtLocation_Analysis_1.text" ' A
```

or

```
ThisDocument.txtLocation_Analysis.Text = wd.txtLocation_Analysis_1.Text ' B
```

Sorry, from the wording it's still not clear to me but I think you want either (A) the string "txtLocation_Analysis_1.text" or (B) the contents of another textbox in the document you opened, appear in the textbox in ThisDocument.